# Smoothing timeseries data to be used in ARIMA

Tags: python, time-series, smoothing

I'm new to machine learning. What I'm trying to do is smooth a dataset, when plotted looks like this.

[image: Train and test dataset]

The blue line is the training data, the orange line is the test data. The timeseries data is the daily close value of the stock.

Is there a way to smooth it? I have tried applying log transformation, but doesn't seem to have helped much.

The code to generate the graph:

```
#general
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
import yfinance as yf

#ML stuff
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

ticker = "0118.KL"
data = yf.Ticker(ticker)
df = data.history(start="2019-01-01",end="2020-04-30")

df = df.filter(items=['Close'])
train = df[:-30]
test = df[-30:]

train = np.log(train['Close'])
test = np.log(test['Close'])

plt.plot(train)
plt.plot(test)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a moving average. A tutorial can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-moving-averages-in-python-1ad28e636f9d).

From a time-series perspective, smoothing the data does not change much of the identification (e.g. model) in a Box-Jenkins setup (which I assume is what is used in your AI framework). However, if you smooth the data *prior* to training a model with another estimation paradigm, you will probably bias your standard errors and your estimates.

Smoothing the data *after* estimation may help visualize what you are doing, but will not reflect your trained model's forecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of **low pass filter to get the job done**. Most intuitively, a **moving average** takes data over a time span, and provides the mean. Moving this statistic in time gives a signal that loses a lot of its high frequency characteristics. I see a [resource here](https://ipython-books.github.io/102-applying-a-linear-filter-to-a-digital-signal/). Some code:

```
import scipy.signal as signal

h = signal.get_window('triang', 60)
fil = signal.convolve(train, h / h.sum())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 4))
train(ax=ax, lw=3)
```

Interestingly, in the field of quantitative trading, moving averages taken over different time spans [provide important market information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MACD).

In the scope of deep learning, many ML architectures (like CNN) already take frequency information into account, so there isn't a lot of value of pre-filtering it. In fact, this can bias the signal and remove information.